# robot framework selenium get all names in a list

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm fairly new to selenium. Please bear with me.
I have a html code as shown below. I'm producing only the relevant port.

```
<div id="id1" style="display: block;">
   <ul>
       <li id="id2" title="title1">
            <ins class="icon">&nbsp;</ins>
            <a href="#" class="">
                 <ins class="icon">&nbsp;</ins>
                 row1
            </a>
       </li>
       <li id="id3" title="title2">
            <ins class="icon">&nbsp;</ins>
            <a href="#" class="">
                 <ins class="icon">&nbsp;</ins>
                 row2
            </a>
       </li>
        .
        .
        .
   </ul>
</div>
```

Using Robot framework selenium library, I have to display the names of the rows [row1, row2 etc...].
I am unable to find a suitable keyword which does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(note: the answer here refers to the original question. It was edited to ask something completely different so this answer no longer applies to the question in its present form)*

You can use [Get element count](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Count).

Using the html in the question as an example, it would look like this:

```
${count}=  get element count  //div[@id='id1']//li
```

That xpath says to find a div with the id "id1", then find any "li" elements anywhere under that div.

Comment: I want to display the names of the rows as well. I do not want to hard code id of every row. I want to get the rows dynamically. I have changed the question